# jquery with boxy plugin - load and submit a form via ajax

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery

I am using JQuery with Boxy plugin.

When a user clicks on a link on one page, I call Boxy.load to load a form onto the pop-up. The form loads and is displayed inside the pop-up without problems.

However, I can't bind the form to a submit event, since I can't select the form element.

This is the event handler:

```
    $('#flag-link a.unflagged').click (function(e) {
        url = $(e.target).attr('href');
        Boxy.load(url, {behaviours: function(r) {
            alert ($("#flag-form").attr('id'));
            }
        });
    });
```

The alert reads "undefined" when it is displayed.

And this is the form:

```
<form id="flag-form" method="POST" action="somepage">        
    <table>
        <tr><td><input type="text" name = "name"></td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="OK"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, `live()` method must be used to bind an element to an event in this case:

```
$("#flag-form").live("submit", function(){ ... }
```

Presently, live method is documented to be not supporting the submit event. However, I could work it out with Chrome and FF. On the other hand, I couldn't get it working in IE. A better way for cross-browser compatibility seems to be binding the submit button of the form to the click event.

```
$("#flag-form-submit").live("click", function(){
```

Answer (score 1):

First (a minor point, but a potential source of trouble), it should be `id="flag-form"` not `id = "flag-form"` (no spaces).

Second, you shouldn't need `r.find()`.  Just do `$("#flag-form").attr("id")`

Comment: +1 - For beating me to it. Just had to discard the very same two points.

Comment: Thanks. r.find() is just one of the many ways I tried to select the form. Unfortunately, the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

I learnt that declaring methods in `behaviours: function (e) {}` works, in addition to using live() methods.

E.g.:

```
$('#flag-link a.unflagged').click (function() {
    Boxy.load(this.href, {
      behaviours: function(r) {
        r.find('#flag-form').bind('submit', function() {
          // do on submit e.g. ajax calls etc.
        });
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Boxy opens the URL (`url = $(e.target).attr('href');`) in an iframe. So you cannot find the form from the opening page(parent page). Your code to bind the form should be in the child page (ie, the Boxy iframe). You can check the iframe URL using your code, `url = $(e.target).attr('href');`